# cURL escape & in data

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I wrote a script to run with GitLab CI and update badges, but i not getting it right

here is the fuction:

```sh
vuejs_version() {

    vuejs_version='x.y.z'

    vuejs_badge_id=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$BADGE_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/badges" | jq -c 'map(select(.name | contains("vuejs")))[0].id')

    response=$(curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$BADGE_TOKEN" \
       --data "image_url=https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=VueJs&message=$vuejs_version&color=orange" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/badges/$vuejs_badge_id")

    echo "cURL response: $response"

}
```

Than my response:

```json
{
  "name":"vuejs",
  "link_url":"https://gitlab.com/%{project_path}/-/commits/%{default_branch}",
  "image_url":"https://img.shields.io/static/v1? label=VueJs",
  ...
}
```

As the response, *image_url* was missing args:

*"image_url":"https://img.shields.io/static/v1? label=VueJs"*

but it should be like:

'https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=VueJs&message=x.y.z&color=red'

Comment: Run your script like this (assuming it's a.sh) - `sh -x a.sh` - that gives you debug of what it's doing [you'll see if any missing variable values].  If that looks alright then add -v to your curl command - it'll dump what headers are being sent / received - so you can see whether anything is wrong there ..

Comment: Perhaps you need to urlencode the data ?? i.e. `--data-urlencode <data>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Mr R** answered, *--data-urlencode* works like a charm;

also, i created a variable with data and url strings:

```sh
vuejs_version() {

    vuejs_version='x.y.z'

    vuejs_badge_id=$(curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$BADGE_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/badges" | jq -c 'map(select(.name | contains("vuejs")))[0].id')

    data=$(echo "image_url=https://img.shields.io/static/v1?label=VueJs&message=${vuejs_version}&color=red" | sed -e "s/ //g")
    url=$(echo "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/badges/$vuejs_badge_id")

    response=$(curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$BADGE_TOKEN" \
        --data-urlencode ${data} ${url})

    echo "cURL response: $response"

}
```